# Guardando valores em uma função para se utilizar depois

Tags: python-3.x

Olá pessoal estou com um problema, estou querendo saber se no Python 3.x teria a possibilidade de uma função guardar um valor definido anteriormente para uso posterior em outro momento do código. Como mostrado no exemplo a seguir.

Primeiramente segue uma classe construída em um dado momento

```
class login(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self, *args, **argvs):
    super(login, self).__init__(*args, **argvs)
    self.ui = Ui_login()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.ui.button_enter.clicked.connect(self.login)


def login(self):
    user = self.ui.user_input.text()
    username = login_username_db()
    for i in range(0, len(username)):
        if user == username[i][0]:
            passworld = login_pass_db(user)
            senha = self.ui.pass_input.text()
            if senha == passworld[0][0]:
                #emailogin(user)
                load_app(user)
```

A função `load_app(user)` tem a sua construção feita da seguinte maneira.

```
def load_app (user):
    cursor = Database.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f'SELECT app1 FROM `{user}` WHERE ID=1')
    loadapp = cursor.fetchall()
```

Logo a seguir é a classe que em um futuro irá chamar a função `def load_app(user)` apenas para pegar o valor que nela irá possuir (se possivel).

```
class userColaborador(QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self, *args, **argvs):
          super(userColaborador, self).__init__(*args, **argvs)
          self.ui = Ui_userColaborador()
          self.ui.setupUi(self)
          self.ui.btn_exit.clicked.connect(self.exit)
          app = load_app()
```

É nessa questão que não estou sabendo fazer como "salvar" o dado construido na função `app = load_app()` quando chamado pela classe `class login(QMainWindow)` para que a classe `class userColaborador(QMainWindow)` possa pega-lo a algum momento quando chamado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer que esse valor seja armazenado, faça a sua função load_app() como método de uma classe (dentro da classe você define `def load_app (self, user):` e no final você faz `self.loadapp = cursor.fetchall()`. Pronto, o resultado de loadapp ficará salvo para o seu objeto. Outra opção é usar uma variável da classe (estática). Vamos supor que load_app seja da classe login. Seu código seria assim:

```
class Login(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **argvs):
        super(login, self).__init__(*args, **argvs)
        self.ui = Ui_login()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.button_enter.clicked.connect(self.login)


    def login(self):
        user = self.ui.user_input.text()
        username = login_username_db()
        for i in range(0, len(username)):
            if user == username[i][0]:
                passworld = login_pass_db(user)
                senha = self.ui.pass_input.text()
                if senha == passworld[0][0]:
                    #emailogin(user)
                    load_app(user)

    def load_app (user):
        cursor = Database.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f'SELECT app1 FROM `{user}` WHERE ID=1')
        Login.loadapp = cursor.fetchall()

class UserColaborador(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **argvs):
        super(userColaborador, self).__init__(*args, **argvs)
        self.ui = Ui_userColaborador()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btn_exit.clicked.connect(self.exit)
        app = Login.loadapp
```

P.S.: eu troquei o nome da classe de `login` para `Login` porque é comum no python usar letra maiúscula para nome de classe. Fiz o mesmo com `UserColaborador`